# Create Custom Menu showing with each Listbox item Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

[Please check this link first.](http://www.gempak.org/forum/342-ios-apps/136173-camera-ipa-download-version-3-8-%5Biphone-ipod%5D.html)

I have the following questions :

1. I want to create such menu with each List box items when clicked. How is it possible.? because this is not a Context Menu, I want to Create a Custom Menu.
2. I also want to show effects on pic, so by selecting the image, it should automatically be divided and feed into given effects boxes.

I have so many questions more, but meantime, need these one. plz....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if i'm mistaking, all photos that you want to work with, are displayed on the film line ( that black with wholes thing ).

I suggest you make it this way:

1) Create your page like this:

[image]

In the white space will be stack panel with Horizontal staking, which allows you to place photos horizontaly and scroll them

2) Think out the way to hold focused image on center of the screen

3) Menu (Edit, Save etc. ) can be done useng Custom user control (just a grid with items ) and it will apear on picture tap ( Also can be Visual effects aplied like fade in )

Comment: Thanks alot cheese, I got most thing, but still I have to get more, so will post the question, next. Now I am trying, whatever u have Instructed.

Comment: But now plz tell me about the Effect Page, how can I create it.

Comment: How to create fade in effect for menu?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533980/changing-opacity-of-a-grid-creating-a-fade-in-effect

Comment: The User control is appearing on the same location, even click any list box item. I want to appear this user control Near Each list box item, when click. Means, the user control should be considered with each list box item, i.e. when click a list box item, it should appear and when click another item it should appear there. How is it possible.

Comment: And one thing more, regarding Effects, I want to apply FX (effects) i.e. color effect, gray effect etc, so how it be possible. See the image in this link. [Camera App](http://www.gempak.org/forum/342-ios-apps/136173-camera-ipa-download-version-3-8-%5Biphone-ipod%5D.html)

Comment: I think there are additional libraries to Change picture effects

Comment: The User control is appearing on the same location, even click any list box item. I want to appear this user control Near Each list box item, when click. Means, the user control should be considered with each list box item, i.e. when click a list box item, it should appear and when click another item it should appear there. How is it possible.