# How to Animate an Item with a Fade In Fade Out Effect

Tags: animation, windows-phone-8, fadein, fadeout

Based upon certain criteria I need to fade in or fade out items at the top of my page screen. These items contain an Image and possibly some buttons in the future. I came across http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.edgeuithemetransition.aspx for WP8.1, but how can I accomplish this in WP8.0?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Blend to create your own custom animation.Fade in or out can be achieved by adjusting the opacity level of your controls. You can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533980/changing-opacity-of-a-grid-creating-a-fade-in-effect). Another one here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026901/windows-phone-8-creating-a-fade-in-and-slide-in-animation)

As an example, if you want to apply fade in effect on an Image here is a sample code.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="fadeInImage">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.3"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.5"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0.7"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0.9"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

and for playing that animation call it when necessary,

```
fadeInImage.Begin();
```